# Exr data window in compositing

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, .exr

I try to make image compositing with Blender and my sequence images layers are EXR coming from another software ( Houdini ). Many software use a feature of openEXR call "data window". It's make a crop in the full image where you have data. This informations is probably embedded in the exr metadata. Most software are be able to read this cropping informations and get you image back to it's resolution ( for example 1920 x 1080 ). But in Blender compositing module , it's not to be the case and I just don't know if a option exist for that. If I render a image where all my 3D geometry take the place in the screen is not a problem but rendering a layer for a small object taking just some space in the full 1920 x 1080 resolution , Blender show it as cropped around this object. If it's a animated sequence , the crop just fellow the object frame by frame.

Any options or workaround for that ?

Answer (score 1):

Display and data windows are not implemented in Blender.

For those wondering about them, [read page 5 of the OpenEXR introduction](https://www.openexr.com/documentation/TechnicalIntroduction.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the info @troy, this look like still true up until today, is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: You would have to test it. I would think it still is a bit of a broken mess?

Comment: Sadly, I've tested in latest 3.0 alpha and it seem still true, my current workaround is to mix other image with the exact resolution and translate the exr image to fit, it works with still image but I don't think it will work with image sequence.

Comment: It is unsurprising that these details go unfixed for years. It’s half baked things everywhere, creating the illusion of fully baked.